# trigger branch io without open url

Tags: branch, branch.io

I'm trying to implement in my app in react native app which I can trigger the branch without open url when I scan QR.

here I'm register with the branch

```
     componentDidMount() {
    this._unsubscribeFromBranch = branch.subscribe(({ error, params }) => {
      if (error) {
        console.error("Error from Branch: " + error)
        return
      }

      console.log("Branch params: " + JSON.stringify(params));
      if (params) {
        this.setState({ scan: { ...this.state.scan, glassHash: params.hash } }, () => {
          this._getCurrentPosition();
        });
      }
    });

  }
```

when I scan with Qr it run the function onSuccess and I want to trigger this branch.subscribe without openURL. if i openURL it works fine but it's not what i want

```
     onSuccess(e) {
    console.log(e);

    // here i want to trigger the branch



    this.setState({ barcodeText: e.data });
    console.log(e);
  }
```

i found on react-native-branch-deep-links docs about BranchEvent but I don't see any example about it.
I found this

```
new BranchEvent("UserScannedItem", buo).logEvent()
```

but not sure how to implement my custom event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jackie from Branch here.

Branch links do function properly and retain the data when they are used with QR scanners, including dynamic query parameters (params appended behind the URL). If a QR code was used to open the app, you can retrieve the session data by using getLatestReferringParams(). Here's a sample code snippet on reading deep link data:

```
branch.subscribe(({ error, params }) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error('Error from Branch: ' + error)
    return
  }

  // params will never be null if error is null
})

let lastParams = await branch.getLatestReferringParams() // params from last open
let installParams = await branch.getFirstReferringParams() // params from original install
```

More information on using getLatestReferringParams to handle link opens: https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/react-native/#using-getlatestreferringparams-to-handle-link-opens

Regarding custom events, here's a sample class for generating standard and custom events with the Branch SDK: https://github.com/BranchMetrics/react-native-branch-deep-linking/blob/63cfc566ea45a6af0663fc7530c36fdb5dbf75e6/src/BranchEvent.js

If you are still having issues, please send over a screenshot of an example QR code with the associated Branch link directly to support@branch.io and I'd be happy to do some testing!

Best,

Jackie

Comment: hey Jackie, thank you for quick response. if I want just to scan using QR in my app, then instead it will openURL it will trigger the branch.subscribe and give me the params as the same if it was open... because I don't want the user to open url after scan, i want him to stay on the app and do get popups with some information. is there any way to do that?

Comment: My pleasure, Adir! Sorry for the delay here. Could you explain your use case with Branch link a bit further? For some context, Branch link is designed for routing users to a specific content of an app with link params. This can be achieved from outside the app or within the app.